Angular testCases are failing with node_modules/moment/moment"' can only be default-imported using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag
My Angular application got compiled successfully, But Its failing while I run grunt karma:unit testcases with below error,
node_modules/moment/moment"' can only be default-imported using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag

Even though I have added this entry in my tsconfig.json:
"compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "es2020",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "importHelpers": false,
        "target": "es6"
}

Please share your ideas.

please check all imports of moment, it should be like import * as moment from 'moment';

If I use  import * as moment from 'moment'  Receiving the below error This expression is not callable.
Type 'typeof moment' has no call signatures.
120         value: moment(moment().subtract(value as number, 'days').toDate()).format('YYYY-MM-DD') @NarenMurali


try changing import moment from 'moment' might require vs code restart

@NarenMurali If I change to import moment from 'moment' gettign the actula error  can only be default-imported using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag which I posted the question.

try esModuleInterop: false and checking, with these two types of imports

Still the same.

after the change esModuleInterop: false from true.It passed. Is there would be any impact?

I am not sure, maybe do this fix only for test cases using tsconfig.spec.json, documentation
